# Append and set listener on generated elements

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I got a problem where the second element that has been generated by pressing the button didn't interact with event handler, even browser has labeled on it as event[image]

here's the code structure, with event handler on it
[image]

The goals it self :
1. To set the `<select>` element based on first element containing `id's` beside it, and set it values from ajax call

Here's some progress I did :

```php
<script>
    $('#pengisian').on('change', '#kota', function(){
        let pilihan = $('#kota').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'localhost/test.php',
            data: {id_kota : pilihan},
            type: "POST",
            success: function(data, response){
                $('#kota_detail').empty();
                var parseIt = $.parseJSON(data)
                $.each(parseIt, function(a, k) {
                  $('#kota_detail').append('<option value="'+k[0]+'">'+k[1]+'</option>');
                });
            }
        });
    });

    $('#tambahDestinasi').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
            $('#tambahDestinasi').clone(true);
        $('#pengisian').append(
            '<br><div id="wrapperTujuan">'+
            '<select id="kota" name="kota_tujuanA[]">'+
            <?php
            foreach($rX as $rtL){
            ?>
            '<option value="<?= $rtL[0]; ?>"><?= $rtL[1]; ?></option>'+
            <?php 
            } ?>
            '</select>'+
            '<select id="kota_detail" name="kota_tujuanB[]">'+
            +'</select>'+'</div>'
            );

    });
</script>
```

[Full Code](https://pastebin.com/7X4eXU7a)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note:

> The id attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element (the id attribute value must be unique within the HTML document)

You need to replace `id` with `class`

```
$('#pengisian').on('change', '.select', function() {
  let currentSelect = $(this);
  let pilihan = currentSelect.val();
  $.ajax({
    url: 'localhost/test.php',
    data: {
      id_kota: pilihan
    },
    type: "POST",
    success: function(data, response) {
     var selectDetail = $(currentSelect).next(); // `.select_detail` select
     selectDetail.empty();
      var parseIt = $.parseJSON(data)
      $.each(parseIt, function(a, k) {
        $(selectDetail).append('<option value="' + k[0] + '">' + k[1] + '</option>');
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```
<div class="wrapper_tujuan">
  <select class="select"">
   ...
  </select>
  <select class="select_detail"">
   ...
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: it does work. but, since i change one of the select value, the others has the same value, although i changed all id's into class

Comment: You need to know clearly that `id` must be unique and cannot be repeated

Comment: I've added some codes that you suggested, it works for ajax request. but didn't work to expand the ```select_detail``` section. full code added in post

Comment: @Sinyo_1015G ok, it's my mistake. please check again :)